# Python Cryptography generate a CSR with an attribute section challenge

Tags: python, cryptography, csr

I am trying to add a Challenge OID to the attributes section of a CSR using Python cryptography. I've looked into the documentation and so far i've just been able to add extra attributes to the subject which is not what i need. Using the following code:

```
OID_CHALLENGE = ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.7")

csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, cn),
        x509.NameAttribute(OID_CHALLENGE, challenge)
    ]))
```

This generates the cert with the following subject line:

```
        Subject: CN=G9P3AwtMlj5RC9QF31GsMDsqzcn1rlBu/challengePassword=3F33A8D3B20CD3DC6016
```

What i need to achieve is the following:

```
 Attributes:
            challengePassword        (unable to print attribute)
```

Is there a way to do this using python cryptography (ideally) or a similar library?

Comment: `add_extension(extension, critical)`? Note that it is called an *attribute* extension in full.

Comment: sorry, can you provide a link to the docu for that extension? Also i found a pull request open which leads me to believe this is not supported yet: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/pull/4857

Comment: I was thinking about [this one](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder.add_extension)

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are not supported in the CSR Builder as of version 2.6.1. `cryptography` prioritizes feature work by requests/use case so if you could open an issue/comment on an existing issue/PR explaining exactly what you need that would be useful!

Comment: As of version 3.0 cryptography supports this.